# Not able to run cron jobs with django

Tags: python, django, cron

I followed this link to schedule a cron job:
https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab
However, it is not working. Here are snippets of my code.
settings.py:

```
CRONJOBS = [
('2 * * * *', 'LeaveManagement.cron.team_notification' , ' >> /home/nineleaps/Nineleaps/LeaveTracking/cronLog.log')]
```

cron.py:

```
def team_notification():
     send_mail("Test", "Hey", 'settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER', ['mahima@nineleaps.com'],fail_silently=False)
```

Running crontab -l command gives this:

> 2 * * * * /home/nineleaps/Nineleaps/LeaveTracking/venv/bin/python /home/nineleaps/Nineleaps/LeaveTracking/manage.py crontab run 5f84ef47012b65076a7f598581193a10  >> /home/nineleaps/Nineleaps/LeaveTracking/cronLog.log 2>&1 # django-cronjobs for LeaveTracking

Comment: What is not working? It seems to add you cron job to the crontab as you wanted.

Comment: I am adding the cron job by using the command "python manage.py crontab add". It is adding the cron job successfully. Still I am not getting any mail. I tried just printing something to a log file instead of sending mail, still nothing is getting printed in the log file